# Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of ServletServerContainerFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-websocket

I have a problem trying to upgrade a spring project from 4.3.2 to the latest ones.
The project uses: 4.1.1.Release security and 4.3.2 Spring framework.
I am trying to upgrade them to 5.3.13Release and 5.2.19.Release for spring only.

App also uses websockets:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.ServletServerContainerFactoryBean

The spring dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Your dependencies are a mess. You are combining spring boot (whatever version) with incompatible Spring versions. If you are using Spring Boot you cannot simply upgrade the Spring version as the Spring Boot version in use is build for a certain Spring version.

Comment: Yes. It is not my project tbh. It is a project i was given to upgrade. But i keep facing this issue.

Comment: As stated you cannot simply upgrade spring when using spring boot. You need to upgrade spring boot and while you are at it fix the dependency mess. Fixing that will make your live a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you cannot upgrade Spring for Spring Boot as that is tied to a specific Spring major version. To upgrade Spring you would need to upgrade to a newer Spring Boot version.

Secondly, your dependencies are a mess. A lot of exclusions that aren't needed and additional dependencies that aren't needed either.

A cleaned up version

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This is for the Spring (Boot) dependencies. Remove the `spring.version` and `spring-security.version` unless you really want to override it (which can be done within the same major version!) but you are probably better of using a new Spring Boot version (update the version of the parent).

There are probably a lot more dependencies (the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` already pulls in hibernate, so you can probably remove that explicit one as well).

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I tried this configuration and removed the unneccessary dependencies, but am still getting the error. :(

Comment: Your list propably wasn't extensive / complete so there is probably more. Also you should remove the `spring.version` and `spring-security.version` from your `<properties>` block.

Comment: A mail sender dependency was missing so I added it and put all spring boot dependencies to version 1.5.22.RELEASE. And again :

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:
hr.igea.webgis.web.websocket.WebSocketConfig.createWebSocketContainer(WebSocketConfig.java:23)
//etc 
Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.ServletServerContainerFactoryBean

Comment: With the help of those dependencies and with some other dependecies versions (jackson) i had to fix, the project run Successfully. Thank you very much M. Deinum.